# Python selecting lists with for loop

Tags: python, list, append

There are my lists:

```
i1,i2,i3,i4,i5 = [],[],[],[],[]
```

and I need the string `"test"` to be appended to each list. How can I do that?

I thought about using a loop but couldn't manage to do that.

Are there any other ways to append to all the five lists?

Comment: I didn't understand where each sentence starts and ends in your text. That makes it even harder for me to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Make a list of lists: `i_list = [[], [], [], [], []]`.

Comment: Do you want to fill the lists with the string 'test' or you want to change each name of the variables i1,i2,... to i1_test, i2_test,... ?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better like there is 5 lists and one word and that word should append all of the lists what is difficult to not understanding

Comment: @Rabinzel and want to fill the lists

Answer (score 1):

easy busy

```py
i1,i2,i3,i4,i5 = 5*[['test']]
```

Comment: This is not the right answer. The RHS will be ["test","test","test","test","test"] and the value of i1,i2,i3,i4,i5 will be "test" and not ["test"]

Comment: sory , I fix, try it now

Comment: Now it's perfect